# Trying to get the BMR to show without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Below is my code and I got a feeling I am really doing this wrong. I am new to react and I been spending many hours trying to figure this out with no luck.

I am trying to get users to input values of age, gender, height, weight etc..and then make the BMR box update with a value.

What i have so far is when the user clicks "Calculate for BMR" the onClick function spits out the correct result, but I have no clue how to get the value to appear in the "BMR input box" without any sort of refreshing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 class Calculator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        this.handleGenderChange = this.handleGenderChange.bind(this);
        this.handleAgeChanged = this.handleAgeChanged.bind(this);
        this.handleWeightChanged = this.handleWeightChanged.bind(this);
        this.handleFeetChanged= this.handleFeetChanged.bind(this);
        this.handleInchesChanged=this.handleInchesChanged.bind(this);


    }

    handleGenderChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({Gender: event.target.value});
    }

    handleAgeChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({Age: event.target.value});
    }

    handleWeightChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({Weight: event.target.value});
    }

    handleHeightChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({Height: event.target.value});
    }

    handleFeetChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({Feet: event.target.value});
    }
    handleInchesChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({Inches: event.target.value});
    }
    onClick= (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);

        const totalHeight = Number(this.state.Feet) * 12 + Number(this.state.Inches);

        if(this.state.Gender == 'Male'){
            var BMR = 66 + (6.23 * Number(this.state.Weight)) + (12.7 * totalHeight) - (6.8 * Number(this.state.Age));
            console.log(BMR);
        }

        if(this.state.Gender == 'female'){
            var BMR = 655 + (4.35 * Number(this.state.weight)) + (4.7 * totalHeight) - (4.7 * Number(this.state.age));
            console.log(BMR);
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                    <Container>
                        <form>
                            <h3>Calories/TDEE Calculator</h3>

                            <div className="form-group">
                            <select className="form-control" value={this.state.Gender} onChange={this.handleGenderChange}>
                                <option disabled selected value> -- Gender-- </option>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="Age">Age</label>
                                <input className="form-control" 
                                onChange={this.handleAgeChanged} 
                                type="input" 
                                id="Age" 
                                name="Age" 
                                placeholder="Enter an Age"
                                value={this.state.Age} 
                                /> 
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="Weight">Weight (lbs)</label>
                                <input className="form-control" 
                                onChange={this.handleWeightChanged} 
                                type="input" 
                                id="Weight" 
                                name="Weight" 
                                placeholder="Enter Weight"
                                value={this.state.Weight} 
                                /> 
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label>"Height (Ft/In)"</label>
                                <input type="input" 
                                name="Feet"  
                                placeholder="Feet" 
                                onChange={this.handleFeetChanged} 
                                value={this.state.Feet} 
                                 /> 

                                <input type="input" 
                                name="Inches" 
                                placeholder="Inches" 
                                onChange={this.handleInchesChanged} 
                                value={this.state.Inches}
                                /> 
                           </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label>BMR</label>
                                <input className="form-control" 
                                id="BMR" 
                                name="BMR" 
                                value= ""
                                /> 
                            </div>
                            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click for BMR</button> <br />

                            &nbsp; &nbsp;

                        </form>

                    </Container>

            </div>


        );
    }

}
export default Calculator;
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks everyone for taking your time to help, it worked :D. I learned from all your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything that renders `this.state.BMR` so it's not too   surprising you don't see it anywhere. Some advice: don't use nonbreaking spaces and `<br>`: that's what CSS is for. Also, don't use bind, use arrow notation to preserve `this`, there is *no* reason to use all these `bind` calls in your constructor.

And then for the actual question: you need to actually render something, so have an element that either shows the button, or shows the BMR value, based on whether you computed it:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleGenderChange(evt) {
    // you really should validate this
    this.setState({Gender: event.target.value});
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return <div>
      ...
        <inputelement onChange={evt => this.handleInchesChanged(evt) } />
      ...
      { this.showButtonOrResult() }
    </div>;
  }

  showButtonOrResult() {
    // if the button wasn't clicked yet, then `BMR` will not yet be a state value
    if (!this.state.BMR) {
      return <button className="..." onClick={evt => this.onClick(evt)>Click for BMR</button>
    } 
    // if it IS a state value, just render it
    return <div>Your BMR is: { this.state.BMR }</div>;
  }
}
```

So when your button is clicked, you do what you do, calculate BMR, then `setState` that, and `render()` automatically gets called again. Now there is a value to show, and instead of the button, it'll show a div with the result.

Also note that we are *absolutely not* using `bind(this)` in the constructor, because that's ridiculous. Properly handle your events with an arrow function so that you get the event, and then pass the event to the correct function, with normal `this` context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to label your state properties correctly. Your female calculation is going to spit out NaN because you're using {this.state.weight} when you're setting it as 'Weight'

Initialize your state

```
this.state = {
  bmr: ''
};
```

Set the value of your input

```
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>BMR</label>
          <input className="form-control"
            id="BMR"
            name="BMR"
            value={this.state.bmr}
          />
        </div>
```

Set the state in your onclick function

```
onClick = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

let BMR;

const totalHeight = Number(this.state.Feet) * 12 + Number(this.state.Inches);

if (this.state.Gender === 'Male') {
  BMR = 66 + (6.23 * Number(this.state.Weight)) + (12.7 * totalHeight) - (6.8 * Number(this.state.Age));
  this.setState({ bmr: BMR });
} else if (this.state.Gender === 'Female') {
  BMR = 655 + (4.35 * Number(this.state.Weight)) + (4.7 * totalHeight) - (4.7 * Number(this.state.Age));
  this.setState({bmr: BMR});
}
}
```